# htaccess redirect localhost

Tags: macos, .htaccess, redirect

I have

```
<link href="/smarter-computing/us/en/sc-mobile.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/smarter-computing/js/sc-common.js?fileversion-r21" type="text/javascript">//</script>
```

When I am working on these files locally I have to keep append `//localhost/~vc/` before the path for JS and CSS files. I don't want to keep copy/pasting this path for the following and every `<img>` links in my code.
How can I use htaccess to redirect all url's pointing to `//localhost/smarter-computing/` or `/smarter-computing/` to append this path `//localhost/~vc/` before my `/smarter-computing` path.

Thank you,

Vishwas

Answer (score 1):

You can either make the document root your home directory in your apache config in localhost, or add this to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/~vc/">
```